# Making a function that defaults to aliasing an externally defined symbol in gcc/ld

Tags: c, gcc, ld, elf

I have a header-only library that's currently calling `malloc` and `free`

This header is included in a lot of different static libraries, which are used to build differently configured programs.

I would like to be able to replace those calls with calls into another allocator, at link time -- based on whether that allocator library is included in the link step, without affecting other calls to `malloc` and `free`.

My idea is to have the library call `customizable_malloc` and `customizable_free` and have those symbols resolve to `malloc` and `free` "by default" -- then the allocator library can provide alternate definitions for `customizable_malloc` and `customizable_free`

However, I messed around with weak/alias/weakref attributes and I can't seem to get anything to work. Is there a way to do this?

**Note:** I know I can create an extra layer of indirection: `customizable_malloc` could be a weak alias to a function that calls malloc. But that adds a level of indirection that seems unnecessary.

Ideally, here's the steps I want the linker to take when it comes across a call to customizable_malloc:

1. Check if a definition for customizable_malloc exists
2. If it does, call it
3. If it does not, behave as if the call was to regular malloc.

**Clarifying note:** In a single-target scenario, this could be done with `#define`. The library could create macros `customizable_malloc` and `customizable_free` that default to `malloc` and `free`. However, this doesn't work in this case since things are being built into static libraries without knowledge of whether there's an override.

Comment: `in the link step` Just link with your own `malloc` implementation. But anything more, read [overwriting malloc from glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Hooks-for-Malloc.html).

Comment: @KamilCuk the issue is that I don't want to globally override malloc and free -- I want to specifically change the behavior of this library. (The reasons for this aren't really worth getting into).

Comment: Then you have to rename them, to for example `customizable_*`. Then it's strange you couldn't get it working with weak symbols (most probably you are hitting the case where the order of static libraries matters when resolving weak symbols, interest in `-Wl,--whole-archive`). Please provide an [MCVE] then. A _really_ simple way would be to use static function pointers.

Answer (score 2):

The extra level of indirection is the only way to do it. ELF (and other real-world binary format) symbol definition syntax (including for weak symbols) does not provide any way to provide a definition in terms of a reference to an external definition from somewhere else.

Just do the wrapper approach you're considering. It's simple, clean, and relative to the cost of `malloc`/`free` it's not going to make any big difference in performance.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve desired outcome using GNU-ld [--defsym](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html) option.

Example:

```c
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void *custom_malloc(size_t sz);

int main()
{
  void *p = custom_malloc(1);
  void *q = malloc(42);  // important: malloc needs to be referenced somewhere
  printf("p = %p, q = %p\n", p, q);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling this with `gcc -c t.c` will (naturally) fail to link with unresolved reference to `custom_malloc` (if the library providing `custom_malloc` is not used):

```
$ gcc t.o 
/usr/bin/ld: t.o: in function `main':
t.c:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `custom_malloc'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Adding `--defsym=custom_malloc=malloc` solves this:

```
$ gcc t.o -Wl,--defsym=custom_malloc=malloc && ./a.out
p = 0x558ca4dc22a0, q = 0x558ca4dc22c0
```

P.S. If `malloc` is not linked into the program (i.e. if I comment out the `// important` line), then `--defsym` fails:

```
$ gcc t.c -Wl,--defsym=custom_malloc=malloc && ./a.ou
/usr/bin/ld:--defsym:1: unresolvable symbol `malloc' referenced in expression
...
```

But that is (I believe) not very relevant to your scenario.

P.P.S. As R correctly stated, the "extra level of indirection" could be a single unconditional `JMP malloc` instruction, and the overhead of such indirection is unlikely to be measurable.